# Rails 5.1 search by date and string filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, search, filter, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm doing a rails app for my expenses
Basically I have a User table and a Spending table with a relation between each of them ( user has_many spendings, spending belongs_to users )
I looped trough all the spendings from all users in a index with a title, a date and a user_id. I added a search button on this index to find the spending according to a specific range date and I would like to be able to sort as well depending on the user_id.
I have this in my index.html.erb :

```
<p>
<%= form_tag spendings_path, method: :get do %>
    <%= date_field_tag "search[date_from]", @search.date_from, class: 'form-control col-2 d-inline-block' %>
    <%= date_field_tag "search[date_to]", @search.date_to, class: 'form-control col-2 d-inline-block' %>
    <%= select_tag :user_id, options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, :id, :firstname, params[:user_id]), include_blank: true, class: 'form-control col-2 d-inline-block' %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-secondary col-1 d-inline-block'" %>
<% end %>
```

This shows me properly what I want and the URL becomes this when I search with a user selected :

```
http://localhost:3000/spendings?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search%5Bdate_from%5D=2017-12-20&search%5Bdate_to%5D=2018-01-20&user_id=&commit=Search
```

I created a model called spending_search where I put this :

```
class SpendingSearch
attr_reader :date_from, :date_to, :user_id


def initialize(params)
    params ||= {}
    @date_from = parsed_date(params[:date_from], 1.month.ago.to_date.to_s)
    @date_to = parsed_date(params[:date_to], Date.today.to_s)
    @user_id = params[:user_id]
end

def scope
    Spending.where("date BETWEEN ? AND ? AND user_id = ?", @date_from, @date_to, user_id)
end



private

def parsed_date(date_string, default)
    Date.parse(date_string)
rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
    default
end

end
```

Here is my spendings_controller :

```
def index
    @search = SpendingSearch.new(params[:search])
    @spendings = @search.scope
end
```

And this is my loop in the index :

```
<% @spendings.reverse_each do |spending| %>
```

With different datas showing obvisouly.

The problem is that I can't get any result with this. For some reason I don't know it doesn't show me the result with the user_id. I'm missing something here but what ?
If I try to modify the scope this in the spending_search model :

```
def scope
    Spending.where("date BETWEEN ? AND ?", @date_from, @date_to)
end
```

Then I got some results by date but of course no user "filter".
Can anyone help me out with this ?

Thanks alot

Comment: I tried to change the spending_search model. The initialize(params) if I put @user_id = 1. I get all the results for my first user according to the date. It looks like that I can't get the user_id go trough the params via the form. I have it in the URL but not in the search. Is it coming from my index then ? Maybe I'm not calling the user_id properly. In the console when I search, it's written user_id = NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show the logs after you submit the form? You will see the params passed to the controller. I think the user_id is not in params[:search], but params[:user_id]. Maybe if you change the view this way:

```
<%= select_tag "search[user_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, :id, :firstname, params[:user_id]), include_blank: true, class: 'form-control col-2 d-inline-block' %>
```

You are also missing @ in "user_id" in scope function:

```
def scope
  Spending.where("date BETWEEN ? AND ? AND user_id = ?", @date_from, @date_to, @user_id)
end
```

Comment: Good ogd this is it ! I wasn't far after all ^^  
Thank you so much !  
In the scope I had the @ actually, maybe I figured it out  
It was just the "search[user_id]"...  
Thanks again !